# File Saving Under Wrong IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, save, filenames

I have been using two separate IDE's for my coursework (jGRASP and Netbeans). Whenever I attempt to save a file in Netbeans, the file automatically saves as a "jGRASP Java file" instead (see picture below). When I open the project from file explorer it automatically opens jGRASP instead of Netbeans, even though I saved the project while using Netbeans. Is there a way to ensure that projects I work on in Netbeans do not save as jGRASP files? When submitting my assignments, I have been instructed to ensure they are Netbeans projects (not any other IDE).

[image: picture of file explorer saving under jGRASP Java files]

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like to me, is the file association for .java files in your computer are set to use jGRASP, you should be able to just change the association in your PC and it would be fine. They are just .java files so if you submit them it should be ok, but you can change it.

**https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-default-programs-in-windows-10-e5d82cad-17d1-c53b-3505-f10a32e1894d**

Answer (score 0):

To explain a bit more, there is nothing in the file itself that indicates which application saved it. A source file is just plain text, and what you see when editing it is all that is there.